# Sinc "Fourier transform" over finite domain

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I'm interested in finding a nice representation of
$$
\int_{-j}^{n-1-j} \mathrm{sinc}(\pi x)\exp(-ikx)  \mathrm{d}x
$$
where $n,j$ are integers with $0 \le j < n$.

Maple gets nothing, and Wolfram alpha says "standard computation time exceeded".

I can do it numerically (of course), but another representation would be cool to have; asymptotics and other approximations are welcome.

Comment: There is no really simpler form, it reduces to the primitive of $e^{iax} sinc(x)$ thus to the primitive of $\frac{e^x}{x}$ which is a special function. The Fourier transform of $sinc(x) 1_{x \in [a,b]}$ is $1_{k \in [-c,c]} \ast e^{idk} sinc(k/(b-a))$ from which you know the asymptotic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @reuns wrote in comments, the antiderivative is quite simple if you accept special functions (the exponential integral function).

Consider
$$I=\int \frac {e^{i \pi x}} x e^{-i k x} \,dx=\int \frac{e^{i (\pi -k) x}}{x}\,dx=\text{Ei}(i (\pi -k) x)$$
$$J=\int \frac {e^{-i \pi x}} x e^{-i k x} \,dx=\int \frac{e^{-i (\pi+k ) x}}{x}\,dx=\text{Ei}(-i (\pi+k ) x)$$ which make
$$\int \frac{\sin(\pi x)}x e^{-i k x} \,dx=\frac{i }{2 \pi }\big(\text{Ei}(-i (\pi+k ) x)-\text{Ei}(i (\pi -k) x)\big)$$
$$\int \frac{\cos(\pi x)}x e^{-i k x} \,dx=\frac{1}{2} \big(\text{Ei}(-i (\pi+k ) x)+\text{Ei}(i (\pi -k) x)\big)$$